# Replace adapter in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, twitter, adapter, twitter-fabric

I am using a ListFragment to display tweets from Twitter by HashTags.

The code for displaying tweets from Twitter is simply

```
final SearchTimeline searchTimeline = new SearchTimeline.Builder()
            .query(mHashtags)
            .build();
    final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTimeline(searchTimeline)
            .build();
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I need to allow my users to change the hashtags dynamically; that is, they may make a search for `#thingOne` and then after viewing the results make a search for `#TwoThings`. How do I accomplish this? When I try to call `setListAdapter` with a new adapter, I can an exception (which really does not make sense to me, as I am not really changing anything except a new instance of the same adapter)

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
```

So does the Twitter Fabric api provides a way for changing the SearchTimeline for an adapter? If not, is there a way for replacing the adapter for a ListFragment?

Comment: I don't think you want to change the adapter, just the information in it.

Comment: Whatever solution works, I will be happy :).

Comment: is there no 'notifyDataSetChanged' for this Twitter API ?

Comment: @DeveloperX you aren't reading the code snippet I provide. Read the snippet and see if 'notifyDataSetChanged' is relevant. I don't see how.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with TweetUi 1.2.0 (which comes with Twitter 1.5.0 and higher), TweetTimelineListAdapters include a `refresh` method which will delete the Tweets in the adapter and make a request for the latest Tweets. `refresh(Callback<TimelineResult<T>> cb)` takes a callback which you can use to handle the request's success or failure. From the success callback, you get access to the latest Tweets loaded, though they're automatically added to the adapter, you don't need to take action on them.

If you're interested in creating a "pull to refresh" style UI, you can see the sample [app](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/blob/master/samples/app/src/main/java/com/example/app/tweetui/TimelineActivity.java).

Courtesy : https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-update-user-timeline-with-latest-tweets-from-twitter/38307

See the [documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/show-timelines.html) also.

Checkout [this](http://pastebin.com/1kqwjudL)

Comment: Thanks for replying. But the answer missed the question. I am aware of the refresh callback. The question is about issuing a new search entirely. The first search may have been about `#apples` and the second search maybe be about `#beds`. Thanks again. Do you know how to do what I just described?